# Getting Entity not found when exporting User Rights from production only

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, impex, flexible-search

We are trying to export all current User Rights from our production environments following the guide posted here:

https://community.sap.com/t5/crm-and-cx-blogs-by-sap/sap-commerce-export-only-usergroup-employee-access-rights/ba-p/13488710

This works fine in 3 out of 6 environments and takes less than 5 minutes. In the other environments the export takes several hours only for it to fail with the following error:

> line 3 at main script: error executing code line at 3 : Entity not found ( pk =  name = 'de.hybris.platform.persistence.core_User' type code = '4' db table = 'users')

This does also not happen on any Test/QA/Dev environments either. Any idea what could be the issue here?

Adding new search restrictions like filtering for the current users ID only. Removing search restrictions to increase the data received from the export (which counteracts the purpose of the restrictions).
Running the export on a single node instead of load balancer. Clearing caches before exporting. Always results in the same error.